# adminer - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, adminer

I am new to docker and container world.  Having trouble setting up mysql client on my local machine.  I am referring to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkp_Dr_4pOA) tutorial.

My docker-compose.yml file looks like

```
version: "3.7"
services: 
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: "mySql-wordpress"
    restart: always   
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p@55w0rD@1234
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    networks: 
      - back
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8282:8080
networks: 
  back:
volumes: 
  db_data:
```

No issue with that I was able to execute `docker-compose up -d`  command successfully.  Below is out put of `docker ps` command

```
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
                                    NAMES
8ecd82867a06        mysql                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   37 seconds ago      Up 34 seconds       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
                                    mySql-wordpress
ae01696e6445        adminer                 "entrypoint.sh docke…"   8 minutes ago       Up 7 seconds        0.0.0.0:8282->8080/tcp
                                    ae01696e6445_wordpressdemo_adminer_1
aa7e1055fc99        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:8181->80/tcp
                                    wordpressdemo_phpmyadmin_1
```

Now when I try to login into `Adminer portal` I am getting error message

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`

[image]

I also tried to install `phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin` Image but getting below error:

`mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]`

`mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client`

[image]

It looks like my SQL server is not setup properly.  Any pointers?

**UPDATE 1**

With the image `mysql:5.7`  I can see below two error messages on `phpMyAdmin`

`mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`

`mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`

Answer (score 10):

If you use docker and, like in your example, your database docker-container is called `db` then enter this as `Server` in the form:

```
System: Mysql
Server: db
Username: root
Password: ...
Database: ...
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with docker, but I had this same **No such file or directory** error with adminer when I tried to login.

I fixed it by creating a custom php.ini file to tell PHP where MYSQL put its socket file.  I had compiled PHP manually so I did not already have a php.ini.  Check if you already have one.

In my case under Debian Linux, I found the socket file here */var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock*

So inside the php.ini file, added this:

`mysqli.default_socket = "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"`

Restart your PHP service.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  this worked in the Docker container I was using as well.

Answer (score 3):

In the docker-compose file in the Adminder service add lines

```
environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: db
```

ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER must be the same name as the service name for your database. In your case, it is 'db'
When you go to localhost:8282, then Adminder should pull the server name automatically.